# ionic Cordova apple platform export .IPA file size huge

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing the IBM mobilefirst platform based Ionic v3 hybrid application and it is working fine. if we going to export the IOS platform (.IPA) file the file size get huge ( 96MB ) and we followed production build as per IONIC guidelines but the build size not reduced. please help us.

Answer (score 0):

just prepare with `ionic cordova prepare ios --prod`

Comment: Hi Jain, still the size same, we could not able to reduce the size of .IPA file now it is 98MB

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected because MobileFirst 8.0 iOS Frameworks are Bitcode enabled Dynamic Frameworks.

Even though the IPA Size is huge but the final app download size will be actually very less while installing it on the device from the AppStore because of Dynamic frameworks. You can read more about the advantages of Dynamic Frameworks [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/OverviewOfDynamicLibraries.html).

Comment: thanks for your input, now if we build xcode 10.2.xx the build size less 29MB only, if we build xcode 11.1.xx the build size increased  until 98MB . is it anything needs to downgrade the xcode version?

Comment: @user2878290 Might be you forgot to turn on App Thinning in the newer release.

Comment: what is turn on App Thinning. can you please help me, where should i enable ?

Comment: @user2878290 app thinning is enabled while archiving the app

Comment: @user2878290 did you see significant change in ipaafter moving to particular MFP plugin version ? if yes what was the old version and what is the new version

Comment: while reply, kindly tag me.